# Need help with maximum safe load on a C10 battery in a Solar power system

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, lead-acid, mppt

I have a solar system with 20Amps/12v MPPT, 150ah/12v C10 battery, 500watts/24v panel and 1000va inverter. I have a few questions.

1. Can I use a 750w cloth iron on this for 30 minutes? As per my calculation, it may draw up to 45Amps from battery, because I am getting only 18amps from MPPT. Will this affect the battery in any way?
2. Can I run a 1HP water pump on this for 30 minutes with a soft-starter?

Thank you all for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Be sure that the 1000VA inverter is a continuous rating of 1000VA. The rating in big letters on the case is often a short term rating, about double the actual rating...

Comment: Thank you Brian, I will check

Answer (score 0):

1. You will drain about 23Ah from the battery.  This shouldn't bother a 150Ah battery much.  It's more than the panel can generate, but then that's the whole point of adding a big battery to the system.
2. 1HP is also about 750W. So if the soft start is soft enough that the inverter will handle it, then the same applies.  But running motors from inverters is tricky.  They tend to draw a big surge current when starting.

Comment: Thank you Simon. I connected the cloth iron, it is working fine.